# Using amsthm: changing Theorem options and break line

Tags: theorems, amsthm

Using `amsthm`, is it possible to change the settings as follows ?

[image]

Theorem/number/Name/cite :

body

I tried to write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {3pt}%Space above
  {3pt}%Space below
  {\normalfont}%Body font
  {0pt}%Indent amount
  {\itshape}% Theorem head font
  {:}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{teorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential][\cite{1}]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility using the [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package to define an environment with the two desired optional arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\thmcite{}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {0pt}%Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {:}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head 2
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{~(#3)}\thmcite}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\renewcommand\thmcite{~#2}}\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential][\cite{1}]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[][\cite{1}]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} Author A. Title A. 2013
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the separation between the head and the body should be increased, one can use an appropriate `\vspace{<length>}` in the sixth argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\thmcite{}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {0pt}%Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {:\vspace{.5\baselineskip}}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head 2
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{~(#3)}\thmcite}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\renewcommand\thmcite{~#2}}\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential]%[\cite{1}]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[][\cite{1}]
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Test 
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} Author A. Title A. 2013
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

New requirement made in a comment: to define some other structures in a similar fashion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\thmcite{}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {0pt}%Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {:\vspace{.5\baselineskip}}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head 2
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{~(#3)}\thmcite}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemm}[theo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\renewcommand\thmcite{~#2}}\begin{theo}[#1]}
  {\end{theo}}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{lemma}{O{}o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\renewcommand\thmcite{~#2}}\begin{lemm}[#1]}
  {\end{lemm}}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{definition}{O{}o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\renewcommand\thmcite{~#2}}\begin{defi}[#1]}
  {\end{defi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Ordinary differential]
Test theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
Test definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}[][\cite{1}]
Test lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} Author A. Title A. 2013
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is the same. Using `\newtheorem` one creates the basic theorem-like structure, and then, with the help of `xparse` the corresponding environment with the two required optional arguments is defined.

All three structures share a counter; this can be easily changed (as well as making the counter(s) be subordinated to an already existing counter) using the optional arguments of `\newtheorem` (see the `amsthm` package documentation for further details).

Comment: How can I change the definition,lemma,... in this way?

Comment: @Angel please see my updated answer. Just out of curiosity, why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the package `amsthm` to define a theorem environment with break-style.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break} % style name
  {}          % space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}          % space below
  {}          % body font
  {}          % indent
  {\bfseries} % head font
  {.}         % punctuation after head
  {\newline}  % space after head
  {}          % Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

Or you use the package `ntheorem`. Here the style `break` is already defined.

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```