# Coloured theorem with bold title and vertical spacing before first paragraph

Tags: color, theorems

I have the following code suggested by David Carlisle.  I do not see the theorem head with a bold typeface.  I would also like to add some vertical spacing after the theorem head, rather than just a newline.

How do I add a colour for the Theorem string and section number?

```latex
    \newtheoremstyle{naiad}%
    {3pt}         % space measure above theorem
    {3pt}         % space measure below theorem
    {\itshape}    % name of font for body of theorem
    {}            % space measure to indent
    {\bfseries}   % name of head font
    {}            % punctuation between head and body
    {\newline}    % space after theorem head
    {}            % 

    \theoremstyle{naiad}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

Comment: Hi, @Ephram, and welcome to TeX.SE. Please read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Post, always when you can, a complete compilable source, so people here know which packages you are using and can also copy, paste and reproduce your results faster. For example, in your case I guessed your were using `amsthm`, since I know the syntax you presented, but it may not be true in other contexts or may even not work if another some other package is interfering.

Comment: Thank you.  You were right, I am using `amsthm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following MWE shows how to edit `\thmname`, `\thmnumber` and `\thmnote` in order to change font typeface and color. Colors are just inserted as example, please don't take them as a good aesthetics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{myExample}% name of the style to be used
{} % {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
{} % {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
{\itshape} % {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
{} % {0pt}% measure of space to indent
{} %{\bfseries}% name of head font
{.}% punctuation between head and body
{ }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
{{\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}} \textcolor{orange}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}\thmnote{ \textit{\texttt{\textsf{({#3})}}}}}

\theoremstyle{myExample}
\newtheorem{example}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{Example}}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{naiad}%
{3pt}         % space measure above theorem
{3pt}         % space measure below theorem
{\itshape}    % name of font for body of theorem
{}            % space measure to indent
{\bfseries}   % name of head font
{}            % punctuation between head and body
{\newline}    % space after theorem head
{{\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}} \textcolor{purple}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}\thmnote{ \textsf{({#3})}}}            % 

\theoremstyle{naiad}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.30,0.30,1}{Theorem}}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{S1}
\begin{example}[Name of the example]
  Text of the example
\end{example}

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
  Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{S2}
\begin{example}[Name of the example]
Text of the example
\end{example}

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
Text of the theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may see some more examples using `amsthm` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123420/140133). There might be also interesting taking a look at [thmtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools).

Comment: It is really good.